# How can I implement stock filter in Magento way?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, layered-navigation

Out of stock products are visible in my magento website. I want a custom filter in the layered navigation which would say "Exclude out of stock" and when customer clicks on it the out of stock products should be hidden.

(by default I enable showing/displaying out of stock products under System-> Configuration-> CATALOG-> Inventory)

i.e. I want the customer to control whether he/she should see the "out of stock" products or not.

example
[this link](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&_pop=flyout&otracker=hp_submenu_mobile)

can anyone help please? I want this to be done in magento way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the development work. you need to hire some one.

basically you need to create attribute for product.

eg. 'exclude_out_of_stock'.

then you need to code in Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

modify `function _getProductCollection()`

FROM 
`$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();`

TO

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('exclude_out_of_stock',0)) {

            $oCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock',0);

            $oProducts = array();
            foreach($oCollection as $_collection) {
                $oProducts[] = $_collection->getProductId();
            }

            if(!empty($oProducts))
                $this->_productCollection->addIdFilter($oProducts,true);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this was what I was looking for... "getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')"  Actually I did the work using simple conditions where I will not display the out of stock products...  But now I can straight away filter it in the collection...  I'll post after I sort this completely