# show all products in out of stock option magento

Tags: magento

I have added exclude out of stock option attribute in the filter list. On clicking "exclude out of stock" option displays only those products which are out of stock. I want to display all the products including out of stock products. Initially out of stock products are not displayed.

I want the functionality like [`http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?p\[\]=facets.availability%255B%255D%3DExclude%2BOut%2Bof%2BStock&p\[\]=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid`](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?p%5B%5D=facets.availability%255B%255D=Exclude%2bOut%2bof%2bStock&p%5B%5D=sort=featured&sid=tyy,4io&layout=grid)

Clicking on out of stock products should include out of stock products in the display.

Thanks,

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290431/how-can-i-implement-stock-filter-in-magento-way

Answer (score 0):

Check this post:

http://colin.mollenhour.com/2009/09/28/yet-another-hiding-out-of-stock-products-update/

Maybe it might be of use

Comment: I tried that example. I want the exact opposite of that ie.by default out of stock products are hidden and when the customer clicks on it out of stock products along with all the products are displayed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/display out of stock products in magento than follow this:

```
A. Login to Magento back-end
B. Go to menu System >> Configuration.
C. Take inventory tab from the left panel
D. Set Display out of stock products to ‘Yes’ in Stock options tab in the right panel
E. Clear your cache and reindex your Index management.
```