# how to add hide out of stock filter (layered navigation) in magento?

Tags: magento, filter, navigation, stock, layered

I am trying to add a custom filter in layered navigation to hide out of stock items.

I tried this way [How can I implement stock filter in Magento way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290431/how-can-i-implement-stock-filter-in-magento-way) and other ways but I did not succeed :(

Please anybody can help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar question here and there on Stack and Magento.stack, looks that here we have and answer:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/magento-hiding-and-not-counting-out-of-stock-in-layered-navigation

from the above answer -> check this module:

http://colin.mollenhour.com/2009/07/14/hiding-out-of-stock-items-in-layered-navigation/